Why is the neutron cross section of hydrogen larger than that of deuterium?
The scattering neutron cross section of hydrogen is about $20$ b, five times larger than that of deuterium. The capture cross section of hydrogen is around 3 orders of magnitude higher than that of deuterium.
What causes this behavior difference? Does the extra neutron limit interactions with other free neutrons, for some reason
Edit: I assume the capture cross section is smaller for deuterium since tritium is a less stable compound, less energetically favourable. Therefore it is less likely to form. Is that correct?
Edit 2: After checking Golub's book on ultra-cold neutrons, I think there is currently no satisfying answer to this question from a theoretical perspective, at least regarding the scattering contribution to the cross section. For the scattering of a neutron with a single nucleus, the differential cross section is equal to the modulus squared of the scattering amplitude or the square of the scattering length  $(f(\theta)=-a)$,
$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=|f(\theta)|^2=a^2. $$
However, Golub then writes:

The scattering length $a$ could be calculated for each isotope if a
good model for the interaction potential was available. In practice one uses $a$ as an experimentally determined parameter.

Assuming a square potential allows you to write an expression for $f(\theta)$, however it depends on other unkown parameters (the strength of the potential and its range), which must also be experimentally determined.
This can be extended to neutron scattering from a large collection of nuclei (which is the case I was referring to). The differential cross section always depends on the scattering lengths of the different isotopes, which are all ultimately experimental values.
This book is from 1991 and I'm sure advances have been made during this time. If anyone is aware of more modern approaches to this problem, I would love to know about them.

Wiki says "The total cross-section for hydrogen is over 10 times that of deuterium, mostly due to the large incoherent scattering length of hydrogen", which is useless. Now I got a PhD in nuclear physics (from a top school, even), and spent many hours in deuteron wave function seminars and have no idea how to answer this.

I don't remember whether there are explicable few-body interactions that explain this system. But Golub's textbook (which is mostly about ultra-cold neutrons) has a nice section about modeling cross sections as completely random variables in the scattering length.

@rob Thank you for the recommendation, this book may have some relevant information.

Yes, tritium is unstable, but its mean lifetime is ~half a million times that of a free neutron. Also, tritium decays to He-3, so if we could turn off the Coulomb repulsion and just consider isospin, a deuteron would much rather absorb a proton than a neutron. It would be even happier combining with another deuteron to make an alpha particle.

Also worth noting is the huge change in cold neutron scaring cross section on molecular hydrogen, based on whether the meeting have enough energy (about 15 meV) to drive the molecular orth-to-para transition. In molecular deuterium, the quantum statistics are different, and there is no such change in scattering cross section.

The differences in cross sections are due to differences in wave functions and energy states:

Slow neutron-proton elastic (and hence total) scattering is enhanced by the existence of a virtual $np$ state.
Slow neutron capture by a deuteron ($^2\mathrm{H}$) is strongly suppressed because symmetry requirements prevent the initial S-wave $nd$ state from coupling to the dominant S and D components of the triton ($^3\mathrm{H}$ nucleus) wave function.

Understanding even two- and three-nucleon low energy interactions is challenging and has driven much theoretical work that can fit the observed data, but I don't believe there is any trivial explanation why the virtual $np$ state and the triton state fractions have the values they do.  (For some examples of recent theoretical work on two- and three-nucleon interactions, see the publications of the Low Energy Nuclear Physics International Collaboration.)
Total Cross-Sections
Because of the lack of low energy $np$ and $nd$ states, their total $np$ and $nd$ cross-sections below $\sim 10$ MeV are completely dominated by elastic scattering.
If there were no bound or unbound nuclear states, the cross section for neutron elastic scattering from nuclei could be naively estimated by the size of the nuclei and the range of the strong nuclear force, i.e.
$$
\sigma_{np}\,\mathrm{(naive)}\sim 4 \pi \left(r_n+r_p +\frac{\hbar c}{m_\pi}\right)^2 \sim 1.2\ \mathrm{b}\\
\sigma_{nd}\,\mathrm{(naive)}\sim 4 \pi \left(r_n+r_d +\frac{\hbar c}{m_\pi}\right)^2 \sim 2.3\ \mathrm{b}
$$
where the radii of the proton, neutron, and deuteron are $r_p\approx 0.84$, $r_n\approx 0.8$ , and $r_d\approx 2.1$, and the range of the strong force is set by the mass of the pion $m_\pi\approx 0.14\ \mathrm{GeV/c^2}$.
These naive cross sections are enhanced, however, by the existence of bound and unbound states.  When such states are "shallow" (very close to threshold), their contribution to scattering is "universal" and does not depend on the details of the interaction generating the state.  Their cross-section only depends on $\Delta$, the absolute value of the energy difference between threshold and the state:
$$
\sigma(state)\sim \frac{4 \pi \hbar^2}{2 \mu \Delta}
$$
where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the initial two-body system. (See, for example, Weinberg's Lectures on Quantum Mechanics or the analysis of $pd$ scattering by Tumino et. al.)
Both the $np$ and $nnp$ systems each have one bound state, respectively the deuteron ($\Delta=B_d \approx 2.2\ \mathrm{MeV}$) and the triton ($\Delta=B_t \approx 6.3\ \mathrm{MeV}$), giving additional cross-sections
$$
\sigma_{np}\,(deuteron)\sim 2.3\ \mathrm{b}\\
\sigma_{nd}\,(triton) \sim 2.2\ \mathrm{b}
$$
The sum of the naive and bound state cross sections is consistent with the observed $nd$ cross-section of about $4$ b, but grossly underestimates the $np$ cross-section of about $20$ b.
This large cross-section is due to the $^1S_0$ $np$ virtual state. The nuclear force between two nucleons is stronger when their spins are parallel than anti-parallel, which is why the $^3S_1$ deuteron with parallel $n,p$ spins exists as a stable bound state, but the $^1S_0\ np$ state exists only as a virtual state with energy $\Delta_{np}\left(^1S_0\right) \sim 66$ keV above threshold.
$$
\sigma_{np}\,\mathrm{(\sim66\,\mathrm{keV}\,virtual)} \sim \frac{1}{4}\ \frac{4 \pi \hbar^2}{2 \mu_{np}\ \Delta_{np}\left(^1S_0\right) } \sim 20\ \mathrm{b}
$$
The factor of $1/4$ is because the final singlet state can only couple to one of the four possible ($J=0$ singlet, $J=1$ triplet) initial states.
Slow Neutron Capture
Because nucleons are so small and the range of the strong force is so short, with both length scales about a fermi, their interactions are primarily s-wave when neutron momenta are $p\lt \hbar/$fm, corresponding to neutron kinetic energies $E\lesssim 10$ MeV.  Since the proton, neutron, deuteron, triton, and s-waves all have positive parity, electric dipole (E1) transitions (which have odd parity) are forbidden and even-parity magnetic dipole (M1) transitions dominate.
The initial and final states of any transition must be distinguishable and hence orthogonal. Since the deuteron is mostly ($\gtrsim95\%$) a triplet $^3S_1$ spin-1 state, the initial state in s-wave $np\rightarrow d \gamma$ capture must be a $^1S_0$ singlet. The spatial wave-functions of the initial $^1S_0$ and final $^3S_1$ states overlap almost perfectly, so a magnetic dipole $np\rightarrow d \gamma$ transition proceeds easily.
In contrast, as first noted by Schiff in 1937, similar symmetry considerations instead strongly inhibit $nd\rightarrow t \gamma$ transitions.
According to "Energy levels of light nuclei A=3",  the $^3$H nuclei ground state wave function is mostly spatially symmetric S $(\sim 90\%)$ and D $(\sim 9\%)$ states, with a small $(\sim 1\%)$ mixed symmetry S' component, and $\lesssim 0.1\%$ P wave. (This article also lists many theoretical topics relevant to 3 nucleon systems.) There are negligible contributions from the completely antisymmetric $^2S_{1/2}$ state and from the 4 P states.
The initial spin-1/2 neutron and spin-1 deuteron can be in either a $^2S_{1/2}$ spin-1/2 doublet or $^4S_{3/2}$ spin-3/2 quartet state.
My rough (and possibly imperfect) understanding is that M1 transitions again can't couple initial and final $^2S$ states, so the only allowed M1 transitions are from the initial continuum $^4S$ state which is spatially anti-symmetric.  Such transitions are only possible to the tiny mixed S' component of the triton, so the capture section is also tiny.

I'd suggest that the reason for this behaviour is simply based on the Pauli Principle. In the atomic nucleus, nucleii like to pair up in order to fill the energy shells. I.e., any configuration with odd nucleii is favourable over even nucleii. There might be many second-order effects, but from a first-order approach, this would explain the much higher neutron cross section of hydrogen (1 nucleus) versus deuterium (2 nucleii). In fact, it is the reason why helium-3 is a famous material for neutron detection.

I'm not really sure that explains the scattering cross-section, though, since the neutron is not captured and it simply interacts with the nucleus.
